# UIImagePickerController breaks status bar appearance

Tags: ios7

In my .plist file, I have "*View controller-based status bar appearance*" set to `NO`. But after `UIImagePickerController`, my app behaves as if the option is set to `YES`.

In my app, I present a VC that presents a `UIImagePickerController`.

The problem happens like this:

- After photo picker is presented, when a photo library is picked, the color of the status bar text changes.
- Then once, `UIImagePickerController` is dismissed, status bar spacing
  changes for the rest of my app and all the navigation bar for other controllers displays under the status bar.

Is there a way to solve this without managing status bar in my view controllers?

Comment: The answer in my case was tied to childviewcontrollers. I had to recreate them instead of reusing them.

Comment: This really seems like an iOS 7 bug, has anyone filed a report with Apple?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225978/how-to-make-uiimagepickercontroller-statusbar-lightcontent-style similar question with the simple solution

Comment: Hey @AlexL, do you know why it happens?

Answer (score 193, accepted):

None of the solutions above worked for me, but by combining Rich86man's and iOS_DEV_09's answers I've got a consistently working solution:

```
UIImagePickerController* imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
```

and

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```

---

Regarding this awesome solution. For 2014 / iOS8 I found in some cases you need to ALSO include `prefersStatusBarHidden` and, possibly, `childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden` So...

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
        willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
        animated:(BOOL)animated
    {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    }

-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden   // iOS8 definitely needs this one. checked.
    {
    return YES;
    }

-(UIViewController *)childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden
    {
    return nil;
    }

-(void)showCamera
    {
    self.cameraController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.cameraController.delegate = (id)self; // dpjanes solution!
    etc...
```

Comment: This is the trick (as a Rich86man said): "Since UIImagePickerController is a type of Navigation controller, you're also setting yourself as the UINavigationController delegate."

Comment: what about after dismiss UIImaegPicker..? i set statusbar hide false then it's background going to black.

Comment: Do you have the plist set up as-per the question above?

Comment: Did you notice the issue when using UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary, opening up some album, and then panning back a bit, and canceling the gesture?

Comment: This didn't work for me but using a category for `UIImagePickerController` that overrides `-prefersStatusBarHidden` worked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19977960/246142

Comment: @Shiki --- **for the ALBUM, you have to use the trick of subclassing UIImagePickerController, so NoStatusBarUIImagePickerController**  Quite correct

Comment: This works, although the status bar pops in and out in a very jerky manner. I've filed a bug with Apple.

Comment: I see the jerky movement as well. I have file a bug myself. This only seems to be an iOS 8 issue.

Answer (score 84):

I faced this same issue today. Here is my solution.

In the view controller who calls the image picker, set yourself as the delegate of the image Picker. (You're probably already doing this)

```
UIImagePickerController* imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
```

Since UIImagePickerController is a type of Navigation controller, you're also setting yourself as the UINavigationController delegate. Then :

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```

Replace UIStatusBarStyleLightContent with whatever style you are looking for.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer will work if you have the 'View controller-based status bar appearance' set to NO in your .plist file. If indeed you need to control the status bar in some other view controllers and have this option set to YES, the other way to make UIImagePickerController to behave correctly is by subclassing it

```
// .h
@interface MYImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController
@end

// .m
@implementation MYImagePickerController
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; // change this to match your style
}
@end
```

Answer (score 6):

i faced the same problem.

here is my solution.
put this in the viewWillAppear of the view controller from which you are opening the image pickerview

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:YES];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you try this. I think needsStatusBarApperanceUpdate will work.

```
1 -Set UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to NO.
2- Call [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
3- [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

Answer (score 4):

I found this to offer proper handling, there's two parts.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
...
```

the UIImagePickerController itself presents view controllers, so this delegate works for all presenters on the stack.

the viewWillAppear ensures this view controller itself is always reset whenever a presenting view controller dismisses above it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
Add in info plist: "View controller-based status bar appearance" with value "NO"

Example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19211669

This solution works for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bug. I solved the problem by setting "View controller-based status bar appearance" set to YES and in every view controller pasting in the following code:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

Then my app behaves as expected.

Answer (score 2):

For hiding the status bar in UIImagePicker :

-

```
 (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```

and when UIImagePicker is dismissed to hide the status bar in View controller use the following code :

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this ....

this will work in both cases i.e whether you use  presentModalViewController and pushViewController

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
```

delegate methods

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
}


- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All the above didn't work for me. I solved the issue by changing the presentation style to:

```
imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the above solutions worked for me.

I present UIImagePickerController as modal view controller. After dismissing UIImagePickerController the status bar state was:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = 0 (UIDeviceOrientationUnknown)
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame = { 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

The solution that fixed the problem for me was restoring statusBarOrientation after dismissing UIImagePickerController:

```
UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[self.viewController presentViewController:cameraUI animated:true completion:^(void){ }];

...

[self.viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:animated completion:^(void){
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

This code helped me to customize status bar style.

EDIT: this solution works if "View controller-based status bar appearance" == YES

```
@implementation UIImagePickerController (IOS7_StatusBarStyle)

-(UIViewController*)childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle
{
   return nil;
}

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
   return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

All the answers above is ok and can help.

I had the same problem having to manage the application runned under **different iOS versions**.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

if(IS_IOS8_AND_UP) {
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
} else {
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
}

imagePickerController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then, in delegate:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    /* Cancel button color  */
    _imagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = <custom_color>
    /* Status bar color */
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution which may work in some of the situations.

```
let imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
imagePicker.navigationBar.barStyle = .Black
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]` when your presenting view controller reappears?

Comment: It's probably a bug then – I'd file a [radar](http://bugreport.apple.com) with an example project and fall back to the old system of managing the status bar :(

Answer (score 1):

I try to hide the status bar in UIImagePickerController in iOS7, but I still don't know how to do this. I use

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES
                                        withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
}
```

in the ViewController that call the UIImagePickerController, and set "View controller-based status bar appearance = NO" in the plist file. Hope this can help.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
```

and in the protocol implement, use this:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me...:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing here specifically fixed the problem in that I was having (and perhaps that the OP was having too), so I thought I would share my answer.  Instead of hiding the status bar which I think is a buggy solution (I noticed that it would sometimes leave my app in a state where the status bar was hidden when it shouldn't be). I instead opted to try and play nice with the `UIStatusBarStyles`.

When the UIImagePickerController has its view presented I set the status bar style to default since the default background color is a light grey.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];
}
```

Then, when the image picker is dismissed, I set it back to the `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    //work

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{ 
    //work

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case,We are using 2 steps

In first step:
                Add in info.plist: "View controller-based status bar appearance" with value "NO"

In Second step: Use/call this code with delegate of UIImagePickerController

```
 - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
     if([navigationController isKindOfClass:[UIImagePickerController class]])
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]; 
 }
```

In case of IOS-7 add One more  Function

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 8.1, it seems like they've finally fixed this bug! I was able to remove all of the workarounds I employed from my code.

Answer (score 1):

Using the default iOS 8 behaviour I was having problems with the status bar appearing when I wanted it hidden.

The solution I found was that, directly after calling `presentPopover` from my view controller I did:

```
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
```

I also had to add this to my main view controller:

```
- (UIViewController *)childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden
{
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I had this problem and I was able to solve it by simply implementing a single delegate function.  The background of my status bar is black, and so UIStatusBarStyle for my application is .LightContent.  When I presented the UIImagePickerController to select a photo from the device storage, the status bar was fine.  However, upon clicking into a directory such as "Camera Roll" or "Favorites," effectively pushing onto the navigation stack, the status bar disappeared.  Upon selecting a photo, there was no status bar at all; upon dismissing another modal view controller, only the battery was present, indicating the rest of the status bar may be black as well.

I tried some of the other solutions such as extending UIImagePickerController, but in Swift, you cannot override using extensions.  I then tried to subclass UIImagePickerController and tried to hide its status bar on viewWillAppear() and unhiding the status bar on viewWillDisappear.  I was able to see the status bar hide with a .Slide animation, but since the status bar was invisible upon selecting a directory, I was not able to see the status bar unhide.  Again, the green battery came back with the rest of the status bar invisible upon dismissing a modal view controller.  I also tried overriding prefersStatusBarHidden(), but that function was never called, so I tried calling setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() to ensure that prefersStatusBarHidden() is called by the system, but it still is not called.  Also, there is the suggestion to set the status bar to be hidden on the delegate method navigationController willShowViewController.  Once again, all this does is hide the status bar, which does not solve the problem.  As it turns out, it seems that the status bar style is changed upon pushing onto the navigation stack of the UIImagePickerController.  To solve the problem entirely, I did not have to write extensions or subclass UIImagePickerController.  All you need to do is set the delegate and set the status bar style to remain the same.  This addition made it as if the problem never existed.

```
let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
pickerController.delegate = self

func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(.LightContent, animated: false)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I actually found a better way to set the status bar background color in Image Picker. Basically you need to set the backgroundImage from the navigationBar to nil, because is default in Image Picker has a backgroundImage as a white Image.