# UINavigation Bar changing tint after using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have a app that can attach a photo to an `NSAttributedString` in a `textView`. The UI design has a blue-grey navigation bar with white text.

However, after I use the `UIImagePicker`, the tint of the NavigationController changes to black text.

```
- (void)showImagePickerForSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
    _imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    _imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    _imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
    _imagePickerController.delegate = self;

    if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
    {
        _imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;

    }

    [self presentViewController:_imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I'd post an image of the view before launching the UIImagePicker but I don't have enough reputation points (and I don't really know how to get them either).

And I'd post the image after launching the image picker and picking one and returning from the UIImagePicker, but again, not enough reputation points.

Anyone have any ideas if this is 'normal' or a bug ion iOS?  Any suggestions on a workaround?

P.S.  If you want to see the images, I can email them to you.  Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This indeed seems to be a bug, and has been present since iOS 7 beta 6 (or earlier).

There is another SO post about this with some solutions: [UIImagePickerController breaks status bar appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880364/uiimagepickercontroller-breaks-status-bar-appearance)

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be avoided by changing picker's modal presentation class to be different than full screen (e.g. UIModalPresentationPageSheet)
Code:

```
imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
```