# How to make UIImagePickerController StatusBar lightContent style?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, statusbar

[image]

When I present the ImagePickerController the statusBar text color is still black, how to make like this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just three steps:

1: Add `UINavigationControllerDelegate`,`UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` to your

```
@interface yourController ()<>
```

2: `imagePickerController.delegate = self;`

3:

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```

Comment: It works because `UIImagePickerController` is a subclass of `UINavigationController` and that delegate method is called every time you present another view controller on the navigation controller stack.

Comment: `setStatusBarStyle` is deprecated in iOS 9

Comment: @barndog How can I hide status bar when imagePicker shows? There is a bug where cropped images add y offset with size of status bar since bar isn't cropped out.

Answer (score 4):

Swift solution by writing an extension for UIImagePickerController:

```
extension UIImagePickerController {
    convenience init(navigationBarStyle: UIBarStyle) {
        self.init()
        self.navigationBar.barStyle = navigationBarStyle
    }
}
```

Then you can set the color when initializing it:

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController(navigationBarStyle: .black)    // black bar -> white text
```

---

Alternative (inspired by [folse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21225979/1298835)): When you initialize the UIImagePickerController normally, make this class the delegate (`picker.delegate = self`) and implement this function:

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    if navigationController is UIImagePickerController {        // check just to be safe
        navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = .black    // black bar -> white text
    }
}
```

Comment: The first solution (custom initializer) does not work for me.

Comment: The question was about **status bar color** not **navigation bar color**.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift and iOS 9, `setStatusBarStyle` is deprecated. You could subclass the controller.

```
private final class LightStatusImagePickerController: UIImagePickerController {
    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion and I think this is the right way to move forward! But for some reason it didn't work for me. The calls are getting called, I tried prefersStatusBarHidden as well, and even called self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate in viewDidLoad. Status bar still shows up as darkContent.

Comment: According to Apple documentation of UIImagePickerController you should not subclass the controller. "The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code."

Comment: It doesn't work in iOS 13. The method from subclass is not called.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem having to manage the application runned under **different iOS versions**.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

if(IS_IOS8_AND_UP) {
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
} else {
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
}

imagePickerController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The, in delegate:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    /* Cancel button color  */
    _imagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = <custom_color>
    /* Status bar color */
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the answers above the following worked for me:

Implement
`UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` to your `UIViewController`
and set

```
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
```

Add the following method:

```
-(void) navigationController: (UINavigationController *) navigationController willShowViewController: (UIViewController *) viewController animated: (BOOL) animated { 
    navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem and I found the cleanest way to solve it was to override `preferredStatusBarStyle` in an extension of `UIImagePickerController` like so. This principal can be applied to third party libraries nicely.

```
extension UIImagePickerController {
    open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        if isLightTheme() {
            return .default // black text
        }
        return .lightContent // white text
    }
}
```

`isLightTheme()` is simply a function to determine whether the NavigationBar in that controller is a light or dark colour.

Answer (score 0):

This is the quickest solution I could think of. Create the following category:

```
@implementation UIImagePickerController (LightStatusBar)

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

@end
```