# iOS 9 UIImagePickerController statusBar white

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, ios9, statusbar

The target screenshot want

[image]

First,I have read those link

- [UIImagePickerController breaks status bar appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880364/uiimagepickercontroller-breaks-status-bar-appearance)
- [How to hide status bar in UIImagepickercontroller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760710/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-uiimagepickercontroller)
- [How to make UIImagePickerController StatusBar lightContent style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225978/how-to-make-uiimagepickercontroller-statusbar-lightcontent-style)

All of the links use those API of `UIApplication`

```
- setStatusBarStyle:animated:
- setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:
```

But,those API are deprecated in iOS 9.

So,how to get lightContent statusBar in iOS 9?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figure it out,just post my answer. **Accept any better answer**

1. Set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to YES,or just delete this key in info.plist
2. Make a subclass of `UIImagePickerController`

   ```
   @interface BaseImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController

   @end


   @implementation BaseImagePickerController
   -(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
       return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
   }
   @end
   ```
3. Use this subclass

   ```
   self.imagePikerViewController = [[BaseImagePickerController alloc] init];
   ```

Comment: Can't believe this is the way Apple would intend for you to do it, but it's the only way I found that works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do that in Swift:

```
class BaseImagePickerController {
    func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
    }
}
```

To initialize it:

```
self.imagePikerViewController = BaseImagePickerController()
```

It seems that `statusBarStyle` was deprecated, but `UIStatusBarStyle` was not.

[image]

You can also change the color for just one view controller this way:

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .LightContent
}
```

Or in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the AppDelegate file you can change it in the whole app with this:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of subclassing UIImagePickerController you could use an extension on UINavigationController which UIImagePickerController is a subclass of and override preferredStatusBarStyle(). This gets rid of all issues in this context.

```
extension UINavigationController{

override public func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {

    return .LightContent
}
```

}