# Status bar colour for UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, statusbar

We use blue navigation bar colour and white text colour:

[image: status bar]

However when I create `UIImagePickerController` it changes the colour for status bar:

[image: saved photos]

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I ignored that answer because it was about hiding status bar. But my brain was thinking about another issue. I've just used proposed injection but with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent]`. It works for me. Please close if it is a duplication

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on answer here [UIImagePickerController breaks status bar appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880364/uiimagepickercontroller-breaks-status-bar-appearance). I fixed it with

```
picker.delegate = self;
```

and

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```

Comment: mark your answer as accepted and vote to close your question

Comment: `setStatusBarStyle` is deprecated in iOS 9