# UIImagePickerController hiding status bar issue in iOS8

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, ios8, statusbar

I did this

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```

and it is great in iOS7, but iOS8 have some trouble with transitions in navigation bar between views and says:

> Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state.
>   Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

So, is any known solution to that?

Comment: Originally asked as a comment under [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880364/uiimagepickercontroller-breaks-status-bar-appearance)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Make sure you have a delegate to the imagepicker.

```
imagePicker.delegate = self
```

now define this function

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [viewController prefersStatusBarHidden];
    [viewController performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
}
```

Comment: setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate unrecognized selector

Comment: If you copy-pasted the code previously the spelling was wrong. At least that's why I got the unrecognized selector error