# iOS 8 Bug with UIImagePickerController Image Crop

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, ios8

I am having an issue with UIImagePickerController with allowsEditing = YES.
I am unable to crop the image from the bottom but also I have an extra empty space on top when moving the crop rectangle.

Also in the method.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

I log info and it gives me wrong CropRect (which is not square!)

```
UIImagePickerControllerCropRect = "NSRect: {{0, 357}, {666, 646}}";
UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage = "<UIImage: 0x7f9b8aa47b30> size {640, 618} orientation 0 scale 1.000000";
UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.image";
UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = "<UIImage: 0x7f9b8868e5a0> size {1500, 1001} orientation 0 scale 1.000000";
```

Does anyone has this bug and how do you fix it?

See the picture below
[image: Unable to select the bottom part of image]

Comment: I meet the same problem with u...

Comment: iOS 9 and I still have that problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: I can't believe this is an issue in iOS 9; it seems to have been around for a long time. @RodrigoRuiz - have you found a way around this in iOS 9?

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea how, but i totally removed "View controller-based status bar appearance" key row (just fully delete this row) in .plist file and it fixed this bug

Comment: thanks this actually solved my problem . i knew issue is with status bar but dint know where to change .

Comment: But this enables status bar in all the views. is there any other option?

Comment: may be this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880364/uiimagepickercontroller-breaks-status-bar-appearance

Comment: The only issue with this solution, though it solves this problem, it creates a new one which is the status bar is visible and you can see the battery and time. Does anyone here knows how to sort this out?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't set the "View controller-based status bar appearance" to YES, so  I have tried to hide the status bar when I show the UIImagePickerController like so:

```
 let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

 ... 

 myViewController.present(imagePickerController, animated: true) {
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
         UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
     })
 }
```

Then on the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` I show the status bar, and it worked.