# status bar became visible after dismiss UIImagePicker in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller, statusbar

getting strange issue in iOS 8

i have made made

1. `View controller-based status bar appearance is NO in info.plist file`
2. implemented following methods

   ```
   -(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
    willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                  animated:(BOOL)animated
   {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
   }

   -(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden;
   {
      return YES;
   }
   ```

the problem is when i navigate to photo gallery at time status bar is hidden , but after dismissing it , status bar became visible for entire app .

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880364/uiimagepickercontroller-breaks-status-bar-appearance

Comment: @iBhavin i tried that , but no luck

Comment: @bhavin that question is just for setting statusbar hidden or not. but he has issue with  image picker. Because image picker  will turn on the status bar we need to manually hide it on view will appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hide status bar in view will apear of the class in which  you are calling imagepicker using below code.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
```

Comment: you are my savior

Answer (score 2):

From Plist

Status bar initially hidden Select YES

ViewController Based Status bar Set to NO.
it will work the trick.

Comment: this will work for app but when you open image picker it will show statusbar, even  after closing image picker view..

Comment: this [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];  and above works together