# how to hide status bar and navigation bar when tap device

Tags: swift, navbar, statusbar

How to hide status bar and navigation bar when I tap the device like photos in iphone?
I had used

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.Slide)
```

but it's not working.

**Edit**: I'd like to hide and show status bar and navigation bar, not permanently hide it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303746/setstatusbarhidden-not-working

Answer (score 128, accepted):

With Swift 5 and iOS 12,  according to you needs, you may select one of the three following code snippets in order to solve your problem.

---

### #1. Using `UINavigationController` `hidesBarsOnTap` property + `UIViewController` `prefersStatusBarHidden` and `preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation` properties

Since iOS 8, `UINavigationController` has a `hidesBarsOnTap` property. `hidesBarsOnTap` has the following [declaration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621879-hidesbarsontap):

```
var hidesBarsOnTap: Bool { get set }
```

> A Boolean value indicating whether the navigation controller allows hiding of its bars using a tap gesture.

Apple also states about `hidesBarsOnTap`:

> When the value of this property is `true`, the navigation controller toggles the hiding and showing of its navigation bar and toolbar in response to an otherwise unhandled tap in the content area. The default value of this property is `false`.

The following code shows how to implement `hidesBarsOnTap`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
    }
    
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden == true
    }
    
    override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
        return UIStatusBarAnimation.slide
    }
    
}
```

---

### #2. Using `UINavigationController` `setNavigationBarHidden(_:animated:)` method + `UIViewController` `prefersStatusBarHidden` and `preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation` properties with a `UIButton`

`UINavigationController` has a method called `setNavigationBarHidden(_:animated:)`. `setNavigationBarHidden(_:animated:)` has the following [declaration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621885-setnavigationbarhidden):

```
func setNavigationBarHidden(_ hidden: Bool, animated: Bool)
```

> Sets whether the navigation bar is hidden.

The following code shows how to toggle your status bar and navigation bar by using `setNavigationBarHidden(_:animated:)` with a `UIButton` set in the Storyboard and linked to a `@IBAction`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // Link this @IBAction to a `UIButton`
    @IBAction func toggle(_ sender: UIButton) {
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden == false, animated: true)
    }
    
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden == true
    }
    
    override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
        return UIStatusBarAnimation.slide
    }
    
}
```

---

### #3. Using `UINavigationController` `setNavigationBarHidden(_:animated:)` method + `UIViewController` `prefersStatusBarHidden` and `preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation` properties with a `UIGestureRecognizer`

As an alternative to the previous code, you can use `setNavigationBarHidden(_:animated:)` with a `UIGestureRecognizer` instead of a `UIButton`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.toggle))
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    @objc func toggle() {
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden == false, animated: true)
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden == true
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
        return UIStatusBarAnimation.slide
    }

}
```

---

- Make sure that `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` is set to `true` in your project's *Info.plist*, otherwise the previous sample codes won't work.
- See this [answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45067117/1966109) if you need to target iOS 10.

Comment: Very impressive. I like this a lot. Worked well for me

Comment: This is a great solution. I am using this for an image that is full screen, however when the navigation bar and toolbar animate in, it changes the position of my image. How do i fix this?
Note: My image is inside a scrollview, and my scrollview is the size of the screen without the navigation and toolbar included

Comment: When using `prefersStatusBarHidden()` with the navigation-bar's visibility, the **navigation-bar** won't animate (slide) when hiding, but still animates the slide, when being shown. Didn't find a way to fix this, yet.

Comment: @rohaldb I have the same issue, did you found a solution? EDIT: solutions is to use `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`

Comment: @FelixLieb Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 8 and above you can simply use [hidesBarsOnTap](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/hidesBarsOnTap):

```
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
```

Answer (score 0):

It's appalling that this issue still persists, 6 years later. I've filed a bug as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65888742/235297). Your best bet bet is to use the old (deprecated in iOS 9) API the OP mentioned in the question, combined with `UINavigationController.setNavigationBarHidden()`. Or you sacrifice the animation.