# Navbar not animating while hiding but still animates while reappearing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, uistatusbar

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26281329/4338423) and added a `UIGestureRecognizer` to show or hide the Navbar and Toolbar. Strangely, the Navbar is not silding while hiding but it still slides when it reappears. the toolbar is animating all the time.

I changed the code to:

```
override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
    print("got called")
    return UIStatusBarAnimation.slide
}
```

to see if it's being called when it hides and it is getting called. I also tried setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to false as suggested by the comments from the same answer but still no luck.

I can't find any information about this issue anywhere.

EDIT: here's my complete code:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(toggle))
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}

func toggle() {
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden == false, animated: true)
    navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(navigationController?.isToolbarHidden == false, animated: true)
}
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    print("got called 1")
    return navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden == true
}

override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
    print("got called 2")
    return UIStatusBarAnimation.slide
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Swift 4 code works fine with iOS 11 but does not work as expected for iOS 10. When using it with iOS 10, for some reason, the navigation bar does not animate when hiding and suddenly disappears.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(toggle))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    @objc func toggle() {
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden == false, animated: true)
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden == true
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
        return UIStatusBarAnimation.slide
    }

}
```

---

In order to fix this, you can use the following `ViewController` implementation that uses `UIViewController`'s [`setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621354-setneedsstatusbarappearanceupdat) property:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(toggle))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    private var isHidden = false

    @objc func toggle() {
       navigationController!.setNavigationBarHidden(!isHidden, animated: true)
       isHidden = navigationController!.isNavigationBarHidden

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        }
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return isHidden
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
        return UIStatusBarAnimation.slide
    }

}
```

---

As an alternative, you can also use the `UIViewController` implementation below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(toggle))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

    private var isHidden: Bool = false {
        willSet {
            self.navigationController!.setNavigationBarHidden(!self.isHidden, animated: true)
        }
        didSet {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func toggle() {
        isHidden = !isHidden
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return isHidden
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
        return UIStatusBarAnimation.slide
    }

}
```

---

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26281329/1966109) that shows up to 3 different ways to toggle both status bar and navigation bar for Swift 4 and iOS 11.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
     var isHidden:Bool = false
     @IBAction func clicked(sender: AnyObject) {
         isHidden = !isHidden
         UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
             self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
         }
     }
     override func preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation() -> UIStatusBarAnimation {
         return UIStatusBarAnimation.Slide
     }
     override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
         return isHidden
     }
   }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but this code is not working at all for some reason! I must call `navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden` to hide the Navbar, with `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`, nothing is changing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in iOS 11 navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden always returns false. In iOS 10 this code works correct. I've not found the workaround yet (((