# iPhone 6/6 plus show status bar

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, statusbar

Only with iphone 6/6 plus the status bar is blank, I don't see anything while on iphone 5, ipad 3 (both with iOS8) all work perfectly, I add:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

on

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

I also add: View controller-based status bar appearance NO but nothing, where is the mistake?

Comment: You want to hide status bar ?

Comment: no I want to show it!now I see on top of the page a white bar whitout any info (no batt icon, no clock, ecc...) I want to see the status bar with all info.

Comment: What you ask is default behavior, did you do anything in plist ? or add some code regarding status bar in view controller?

Comment: In plist there is only: uistatusbarhiddeno NO, and viewcontrollerbased status NO, on view controller I don't do anything, in fact with iphone and ipad I have no problem.

Comment: I haven't face this type of problem, but one suggestion is remove that plist field and re-install application in device. also remove coding from didFinishLaunchingWithPtions, / also check by opening other applicaiton like setting..

Answer (score 1):

There could be two possibilities.

- Either this property is present in your plist. `(Status bar style : UIStatusBarStyleLightContent)`  and your `viewcontroller's` background is also whiteColor.

or

- Your status bar is set to be hidden initially or by the code `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];`

Kindly check your view background. It could be either black & the statusBar is also Default or it background is white & statusBar is LightContent.

Hope that helps.

Comment: nothing, I create a normal view blank viewcontroller and status bar not working :S

Comment: Do zip your project & Send it as it is to me : `tiwari.balram@gmail.com` May be after looking at your code, we may get it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add **UIStatusBarHidden** *(Status bar is initially hidden)* with value **YES** in your Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

From the comment above, you mentioned that you want to show the Status bar.

If so, put the following code inside whichever view controller that you want the status bar to appear.

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return NO;
}
```

For the PList:

- View controller-based status bar appearance: NO (means that you want to hide it)
- View controller-based status bar appearance: YES (means that you want to show it)

For more information, please see: [setStatusBarHidden not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303746/setstatusbarhidden-not-working)

The above link is about hiding the Status bar. If you want to show it, I think you can just try the exact opposite.