# iOS 7 staus bar issues

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, uistatusbar

I have an application with status bar hidden. For hiding status bar I did following things:

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

This was working with ios 6. Now in iOS 7 I added `View controller-based status bar appearance = NO`.
I also created subclass of my navigation controller and added:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

Everything is working well but when I present UIImagePicker status bar goes visible and than it never hides back even after dismissing view. I also added `prefersStatusBarHidden` method in the related view too but no success :(

Any help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following link

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)aPicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

// for iOS7
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    }
```

Following are the list of reference regarding status bar issues in ios7 on stack overflow Itself. ;-)

[Status bar and navigation bar appear over my view's bounds in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17074365/730776)

[Status bar won't disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17763719/730776)

[Status bar appear over my view's bounds in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18375898/730776)

Answer (score 0):

Use can use this method for status bar Issue.It should work fine.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
        UIView *addStatusBar = [[UIView alloc] init];
        addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20);
        addStatusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.973 green:0.973 blue:0.973 alpha:1]; //change this to match your navigation bar
        [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:addStatusBar];
    }
```

Comment: I want to hide status bar which was hidden already before image picker get presented. I don't want to add some view behind the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `Target's` general settings.

[image]