# MGSpiltViewController issue in iOS 7.0

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have requirement to change my application old UI to latest flat UI compatible with iOS 7.0. For this, I have to change whole UI of my application. My application works in good condition below `iOS 7.0.`

Now my issue is regarding application status bar for iOS 7.0. My all existing views gets overlapped by status bar in iOS 7.0. For `viewcontroller`, I have a found a solution to resolve this issue but i didn't find any solution for [`MGSplitViewController`](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController).

Have you ever used this control in your application? Do you have any solution for this control? please let me know if you have any suggestion to solve this issue.

Thanks,
Nilesh M. Prajapati

Comment: My suggestion : Please take a Backup first !

Comment: Thanks , I already have it ... I want a suggestion to solve this issue.

Comment: refere this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375898/status-bar-appear-over-my-views-bounds-in-ios-7

Comment: Check below links for MGSplitViewController issues, it should help you, https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController/issues/89 https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController/issues/88

Comment: Hi, Vishwa.. 
Thanks for referring me ...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for help but I tried below solution.

```
- (CGSize)splitViewSizeForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)theOrientation
{
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {// Added to solve iOS 7.0 status bar issue
        statusBarHeight = 0;
    }
} // This one solves my right panel issue.


- (void)layoutSubviewsForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)theOrientation withAnimation:(BOOL)animate
{
    CGRect newFrame;
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) 
    {
        newFrame = CGRectMake(0, 20.0, width, height-20.0);
    }
    else
    {
        newFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0.0, width, height);
    }
}// this one solves left panel issue.
```

*** I also placed below code in all View's ViewDidLoad() method.

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```