# Black strip on top despite statusBarHidden

Tags: iphone, ios6.1, uistatusbar

There is a black strip, of the same frame as the `status bar` on the top of the screen despite setting the status bar `hidden`, using :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

The `StatusBar`hides without any hiccups. But the black strip is persistent. It is causing my `view` to be resized, which is supposed to be fullscreen.

I have tried setting `wantsFullScreenLayout` to YES, in vain.

Is there a way to hide it, or set it's `alpha` ?

I do NOT use any `XIB`s. I do everything programmatically only, so I cannot change any properties in the `XIB`.

To go in a bit of detail, I have a `UINavigationController` with a rootViewcontroller. The user taps an image, and I push [`MWPhotoBrowser`](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser) on it, which can further push other `viewControllers` like this:

rootViewController -> photoBrowser -> otherViewControllers -> ...

-> = `PUSH` operation

If any other details are needed, please tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: status bar need to hidden for whole application than in info.plist file  set Status bar is initially hidden  to YES that may work

Comment: Not necessarily. I have hidden it in multiple parts of my application, where a new viewController is pushed, and it works just fine. It's just in this instance, where i'm not pushing another view controller, but animating in the same view controller, where the black strip is persistent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Status bar won't disappear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763719/status-bar-wont-disappear)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Specifics are: Should hide/show in only one viewController, on user's action; status bar hides, but a black strip in it's place remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a view in the view hierarchy was not resized appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

No. No need to set any alpha value.

Just go through your xib.

1. Select the view of your view controller
2. Go to Attribute Inspector
3. Check the value for status bar, navigation controller & bottom bar over there
4. Set status bar to None if not.
5. Change topbar & bottombar as per your requirements
6. Adjust your gui accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

In the storyboard or xib file set Status bar at "none" in Attributes inspector > simulated section