# iOS 7 Default image overlapped by status bar in multi-tasking view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, ios7

My app is compiled against iOS 6 SDK (haven't gotten the time to upgrade to iOS 7 SDK). So I just noticed that the `Default` image is overlapped by the status bar. This seems to happen ***only*** in the "multi-tasking" view but not when resuming my app from background for some reason.

See this image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think many people will notice this at all.**

However, as far as I know you could possibly disable the Statusbar when the app gets in backround. 
To do this just use this method in the delegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    //code to disable statusbar
}
```

In the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method you could enable the statusbar again.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
//code to enable the statusbar
}
```

Furthermore you can take a look at this previous asked question: [Status bar won't disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763719/status-bar-wont-disappear)

If you got any questions feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

edgesForExtendedLayout does the trick for iOS 7. However, if you build the app across iOS 7 SDK and deploy it in iOS 6, the navigation bar appears translucent and the views go beneath it. So, to fix it for both iOS 7 as well as for iOS 6 do this:

```
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
  if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
       self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;   // iOS 7
```