# Will a hidden status bar in iOS app compiled with Xcode 4.6 be visible when Xcode 5 is used instead?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I installed Xcode 5 and realized that the status bar no longer remains hidden in iOS 7 Simulator. I found this post [Status bar won't disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763719/status-bar-wont-disappear) which has the solution of adding "View controller-based status bar appearance: NO" to info.plist file which works fine for my purposes.

My question is will this affect all existing versions in the store already? So any version of my games that were compiled in Xcode 4.6 will now show the status bar during game play?

I am thinking the answer is yes, but have not updated any of my devices to iOS 7 yet so can not check for myself.

Thanks

Comment: the title doesn't match the question .. actually the title is confusing

Comment: bandejapaisa's answer is correct. You might experience some iOS7 issues, but your allready compiled and distributed apps have nothing to do with Xcode 5 compilation. And Daij-Djan has a point, too.

Comment: If you suggest a less confusing title and I will change it. Thanks

Comment: I changed it but let me know if you think its better or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Apps already in the store compiled with Xcode 4.6 will behave as the did before when run on iOS 7. You may experience other UI issues, but the status bar won't start appearing if it wasn't doing before - not until you compile with Xcode 5 and submit a new binary.

Comment: So would the issue actually be with the BASE SDK as opposed to Xcode itself? Xcode 5 only has 7.0 as BASE SDK, but if 6.1 were to become available on Xcode 5 would that also be the same as compiling on Xcode 4.6?

Comment: Yes this is probably the reason, but I don't think you can submit to apple with an older BASE SDK, so I think this is a moot point. Another differences is that you're using a different default compiler. Xcode 5 is compiling with LLVM 5.0, whereas before it was LLVM 4.0 - but that shouldn't affect sdk behaviour - I'm not an expert on these issues anyway..

Comment: But i dont understand one point, when the application runs in a device - iOS 7.0 +, should it not behave as iOS 7 style, i mean it should come up with all the issues that come with iOS 7.0 irrespective of the fact that it was compiled with xcode 4.6. or xcode 5.

Comment: Not necessarily. Apple must have purposefully made the OS backwards compatible with pre-compiled apps so that they behaved as they previously behaved, otherwise there could be a lot of broken apps out there that hadn't been updated. The same way when the iPhone 5 was released - apps that weren't recompiled still appeared at 320x480 when ran on the iPhone 5 with the 320x568 res screen - as they could have behaved very strangely if not looked at first by the developer.