# status bar not hidden when sharing using AirPlay

Tags: ios, ios7

My view controller hides the status bar using this method
[Status bar won't disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763719/status-bar-wont-disappear)

When I share the screen using AirPlay, the status bar is visible again. Any way to keep it hidden?

Comment: this worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735272/window-for-an-external-display-affects-primary-screen

Comment: Thanks!! I'm going to try it now ;)