# How do I make the green battery icon (when phone is charging) in the status bar of iOS 7 fade when the status bar does as well?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Is this a known iOS 7 glitch? If I fade the alpha of the navigationBar (or even set the status bar to none in Interface Builder) the green charging battery icon still shows up in the status bar, despite the rest of it hiding. How do I stop this from happening?

Here's a screenshot (pretty straightforward):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it might not be a bug but a feature of iOS 7.
Try adding the following method to your app's root view controller:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

Have a look into this question: [Status bar won't disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763719/status-bar-wont-disappear)