# iOS iPad Simulator displays status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uistatusbar

I set the status bar to be hidden but it is still being displayed. how can i change that?
oh and i already checked the info.plist file but it says `hidden: YES`
thanks for help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Status bar won't disappear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763719/status-bar-wont-disappear)