# Status bar won't go away on scaled up version of iOS 7 app

Tags: ios, objective-c

*I have tried everything suggested here: [Status bar won't disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763719/status-bar-wont-disappear) to no avail.*

My iPhone version of my app has no status bar shown, but on my iPad, **which runs the scaled up version of my iPhone version,** there is a status bar that won't go away!

If it makes a difference, my app uses the devices camera for a majority of the app. If you need more info/code, don't hesitate to ask! My app is iOS 7 only, and I use Xcode 5. Also, I would like the status bar gone in the whole app.

**Do not suggest UIViewControllerBasedStatusBar in the plist-- it does not work.**

---

**Related Articles**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18740897/294884

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21034908/294884

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20307841/294884

Comment: You know, this QA actually has a **lot of information** the others actually do not have.  (Plus a hell of an argument started by Vike :) )  Actually it is perhaps a bad idea to close it.

Comment: If you think you added something new and valuable, post it on another question, as tho every likely will be closed.

Comment: what Joe Blows calls argument was just the hint that the technique he uses is not supported and discouraged from Apple. It might work, it might fail. Joe Blow answered, that there are situations, where it is the only reasonable way, iE he usually deals with hundreds of custom view controller classes in each project. I say, if you got in such a situation your architecture is broken, as I usually don't use much more than half a dozen, maybe a flu dozen. but never hundreds.

Comment: And I repeat: If your got to a point, where using subclassing with categories is the only option, you are already on the wrong path for some time. At least for this question it is not needed at all.

Comment: just for anyone googling here, it is now 2017, (fortunately) the discussion above about categories etc is now totally gone from iOS.  you simply add the two items in your plist, that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## For 2016 onwards all you do is:

## Add these two items to your plist:

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

## 1. It is that simple

## 2. There is no other method.

(Note - there's a (pointless) "hide status bar" checkbox in "general settings" "deployment info" section.  This simply reads the plist file, it's a completely pointless checkbox.)

---

## Historic answers...

I've removed the historic answers as they are completely useless. (If any historians need to read it, click "edit history".)

Comment: another question: why `~ipad` ?

Comment: why a potential harmful and unsupported overwriting by category if it could be done without any problem in the view controller subclass?

Comment: and you should teach absolute beginner dirty tricks and promote them as best possible solution.

Comment: JoeBlow and @Branch Please move over to chat when your conversations get this long.

Comment: Also, @JoeBlow on the test app, there still is a status bar there.

Comment: @JoeBlow I also added - (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden but it still shows! At least the errors are gone!

Comment: @JoeBlow What could be the issue? There are no errors anymore but the status bar still shows.

Comment: @JoeBlow Interesting- is this a bug? Does anyone know?

Comment: @JoeBlow Looked at other posts. This could be a bug with iPad mini & iOS 7.1. (I've been testing on an iPad mini, and unfortunately, don't have a full sized iPad). Due to this, I mark your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already, on your **info.plist** file, added two new attributes if not present? Please try setting "**Status bar is initially hidden**" to "`YES`" and also set "`UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance`" to "`NO`". This will hide status bar for your app.

Comment: As I said in the question I tried everything here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763719/status-bar-wont-disappear (including your suggestion) to no avail. Thanks though!

Comment: Yup, in some cases "this just does not work".  I don't think it's worth going in to why here, but that's life.  I would go so far as to say i iOS7 you should not, ever, use UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance.  it is **only** a legacy thing to try to make things work while everyone is "getting used to" iOS7/Xcode5.