# How to completely remove the iOS status bar

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an app that I want to make full screen, but every solution I tried, the status bar is white, and the app doesn't run in full screen.

How can I hide the status bar?

Comment: thanks for the help, i managed to figure out i was missing a function in the view controller
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Status bar won't go away on scaled up version of iOS 7 app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043005/status-bar-wont-go-away-on-scaled-up-version-of-ios-7-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The only correct solution from 2016 onwards:**

in your apps plist file, add two rows.

"View controller-based status bar appearance" ... NO

"Status bar is initially hidden" ... YES

that's all there is to it.

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

So:

[image]

Comment: i tried this, and it gives me a white inline instead of the status bar, and yet the app is not in full screen

Comment: It seems the frame of your UIView is not set correctly. That may be the reason of white line. I can better tell you after analyzing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Target setting -> General Setting --> Then find Hide status bar --> Check these option then try to run app. I think these will solve your problem.

Comment: can find this in target settings - > general settings, the only place i found status bar is in info of the target settings, status bar is initially hidden = Yes