# how to hide UIStatusbar on the ipad?

Tags: ipad, xcode5, uistatusbar

i was create the app for target for iphone in ios7. but when i tested that app into ipad then statusbar not hidden. in iphone its hide but not into ipad. please help me. i set the below code  on my app.
i set this to appdelegate. but its not hide the statusbar for ipad.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

i also set the View controller-based status bar appearance to NO and Status bar is initially hidden to YES into info.plist file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, but since iOS 7 the iPad works slightly different with iPhone compatibility mode: the status bar is always visible, and there is no longer a 2x button to show the interface "zoomed in".

Even though your code will work fine on iPhone, the iPad will always display the status bar on iPhone apps.

Comment: thanks jay. i think it is right with ios7 specially. thanks again.

Comment: i think its fine with ios6 but not into ios7.

Comment: is any possibity for ipad to hide statusbar in ios7?

Comment: Only if your app has an iPad interface or if it's universal. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059703/cannot-hide-status-bar-in-ios7 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763719/status-bar-wont-disappear